# how to convert day to date in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL that has a field publishDay of integer type. I want to change the field name to publishDate and change the type to timestamp and convert values in pusblishDay to date.

Which query can do it?

screenshot from part of table
[image]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Step 1) Add a new column, with the desired data type. Step 2) Update the table, set the new column value to the converted value from the old column. Step 3) Verify the table data. Step 4) Drop old column. (Step 0, take a backup if you don't have any recent.)

Comment: @jarlh thanks but this way is final option

Comment: @jarlh: if the data can be converted with a single expression, those 4 steps can be done using a single `ALTER TABLE` statement. But it's unclear to me how a value like 17518 could represent a proper date.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name pusblishDay that just represents number of day, if Be multiplied 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 convert to date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need in PgSQL is the following query:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1523881100) -- the number is epoch value
```

or

```
SELECT to_timestamp(publishDay) AS publishDate
```

Rest is just conversions.

Please refer how to the following page for how to do date/time manipulations:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

P.S. According to your screenshot the publishDay seem not complete epoch(unix timestamp).